# Why is my answer grey?

Tags: support

My answer to [What's the best strategy for the Steam Monster Game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223693/whats-the-best-strategy-for-the-2015-steam-sale-monster-summer-game) appears to be grayed out. I don't see any notice though. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that the post has a net score of -3 or lower. At that point the system greys out the answers. It's supposed to be an indication to future viewers that the post was generally considered to be unhelpful by the community at large.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see what's unhelpful about it, though. Players still use abilities at the wrong time.

Comment: Like I've mentioned, you're unlikely to ever learn why - while I appreciate you are interested in improving, there is no expectation that anyone must comment, and in a lot of cases, asking people to do so is not taken well by the community.

Comment: I understand, but not everyone is the same. Some to whom the reason is obvious might need a reminder that it is not so to me. That an innocent comment causes bloodlust is the community's problem.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman That "innocent comment" you mention is something that happens with depressing frequency.  After awhile, it gets *extremely* trite.  It's not so much the community's problem as it is every single new user's belief that their demand for a reason must be met.

Comment: @Frank. It's only one comment; just ignore it if it doesn't apply to you. Maybe the many instances of these comments is a sign that such is lacking in the interface. And at least it's more innocent than taking points from a newbie for no apparent reason.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman *Yours* is only one comment.  When combined with the rest of the new members, it becomes almost incessant.  Rather than taking it as a sign that the interface is lacking, experience has shown that the reasoning is incredibly sound, and that new users don't understand what SE is about.

Comment: @Frank The sign of a good GUI is that people don't need to spend time perusing FAQs and whatnot to be able to use it properly. Did i miss anything in my QA?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Yes.  The fact that comments are *optional*.  If they were mandatory, you would have gotten your comment.  You didn't, ergo, there asking is a lost cause, and rather annoying to established users.

Comment: @Frank I understand that people can grieve others for the lulz, but as i've explained above, some may need a reminder that such an *optional* downvote is useless at best.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman *Except that it's not*.  Downvotes are arguably the *most* important tools established users have.  By portraying it as griefing others, it shows you don't understand their purpose.  I'd recommend going to do your due diligence and research their use before deciding their purpose is for trolling.  Until then, I'm out.

Comment: @Frank How is it not useless in this case? I understand the purpose just fine, hence *this case*. AFAIK, my QA meets all site requirements. If it doesn't, please let me know how to improve it.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Simple.  Because community members decided to downvote the content.  They have that capability, and they can exercise that privilege as they see fit.  Your opinion that the content isn`t worthy of that treatment is irrelevant.

Comment: Their opinion is as valid as mine, hence irrelevant according to you, so there's no point to continue this discussion. Not all criteria are subjective, but even those can be adressed. (Should i have added an intro and TIA? According to objective criteria i should not have, but it might be nice subjectively.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking why you received downvotes. Some people are touchy about it, but it would be best for those people to simply ignore their irritation. Understand, too, that there is nothing wrong with the downvoters choosing to ignore your request for an explanation. Many times, explaining a downvote simply leads to argument which they have no interest in engaging in.

Comment: @Sterno Except that the latter case is harmful to one's motivation to participate, i agree.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman From what I've seen, the resulting arguments are often just as damaging, if not more so, since they spill over onto everyone else.

Comment: @Sterno So the best course of action follows the old adage "If you can't say anything nice, don't say anything at all." - Help or move on.